# implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::function::__1::void(int,int)

Tags: c++, qt, templates, instantiation, implicit

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <QDebug>
#include <functional>
template<typename T,typename ...args>
class TestClassA
{
public:

    static TestClassA& instance()
    {
        static TestClassA a;
        return a;
    }

    void Add(int a,T* b,void(T::*)(args...));

    void Remove(int a);

    std::unordered_map<int,std::function<void(*)(args...)>> m_test{};
};

template<typename T, typename ...args>
void TestClassA<T,args...>::Add(int a, T *b, void (T::*pf)(args...))
{
    this->m_test.emplace(a,std::bind(pf,b));
}

template<typename T, typename ...args>
void TestClassA<T,args...>::Remove(int a)
{
    this->m_test.erase(a);
}



class TestClassB
{
public:
    void TestTwo(int,int)
    {
        qDebug()<<"TestTwo";
    };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    auto testCBIns=new TestClassB();

    TestClassA<TestClassB,int,int>::instance().Add(1,testCBIns,&TestClassB::TestTwo);

    TestClassA<TestClassB>::instance().Remove(1);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Hi guys,I'm currently worked with these for a long time,
I attempted to make the member function as the value of std::unordered_map.However,The message which donted with the title are always be reported by compiler,I can't resolve it,please give me an assistance,thanks.

Comment: `std::function<void(*)(args...)>` does not look correct.  The template  parameter for `std::function` should not be a pointer type but a function type.  If you want your function object to call `void(int, int)` functions then that is the type you should give it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thx,bro! I doesn't just want to pass void(int,int), I want to pass the variadic parameter function into std::unordered_map as well. 'std::function<void(*)(args...)> does not look correct' which means that I cannot implement my ideal by this way?

Comment: `void(int, int)` was just an example.  `std::function<void(args...)>` is probably what you need,

Comment: @NathanOliver Thx,Bro!!! Everythings get well. So excllent answer!!!!Thx!